# Ionic2/Cordova plugin

Tags: cordova, ionic2

I'm trying to import a cordova plugin (https://www.npmjs.com/package/cordova-plugin-mauron85-background-geolocation). I imported it:

```
import {BackgroundGeolocation} from 'ionic-native';
```

and called it:

```
BackgroundGeolocation.configure(callbackFn, failureFn, {
    desiredAccuracy: 10,
    stationaryRadius: 20,
    distanceFilter: 30,
    interval: 60000
});
```

But this throws me an error: **Supplied parameters do not match any signature of call target**... I know what this error means but this is an example from docs...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Patrick1870, if you are using ionic-native background geolocation, configure method will return a promise. Your syntax should be as follows.

```
import {BackgroundGeolocation} from 'ionic-native';

let backgroundOptions = {
            desiredAccuracy: 10,
            stationaryRadius: 20,
            distanceFilter: 30,
            locationTimeout: 60000 //interval is renamed to locationTimeout
        };

BackgroundGeolocation.configure(backgroundOptions).then((location) => {
            console.log("location", location)
        }).catch((err) => console.log("Error ", err));
```

If you directly using the plugin without ionic-native, you have to use it as

```
declare var backgroundGeolocation: any;
let backgroundOptions = {
                desiredAccuracy: 10,
                stationaryRadius: 20,
                distanceFilter: 30,
                locationTimeout: 60000 //interval is renamed to locationTimeout
            };
backgroundGeolocation.configure((location) => {
   console.log(location);
},(err) => {
   console.log("error on background Geolocation ", err);
}, backgroundOptions);
```

Comment: Thank you! Now I understand. Everything works great!